# Pinging slower then expected in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multithreading, ping

I have been experimenting with pinging different IP addresses using multithread but I feel it doesn't go fast enough it pings like 3k of IP's per minute what is extremely slow since I have like 17M IP addresses to ping. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
import sys
from ipaddress import ip_address
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from core.thread_pool import ThreadPool

class HostPing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ok = 0
        self.bad = 0
        self.noresp = 0
        self.response_codes = []
        self.output_codes = []

    def create_ips(self, start, end):
        start_int = int(ip_address(start).packed.hex(), 16)
        end_int = int(ip_address(end).packed.hex(), 16)
        return [ip_address(ip).exploded for ip in range(start_int, end_int)]

    def ping(self, address, **kwargs):
        command = ['ping', '-c', '1', '-n', '1', '-w', '2',  address]
        p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
        res = p.returncode
        output = output.decode().strip()
        if res == 0:
            self.ok += 1
        elif res == 2:
            self.noresp += 1
        else:
            self.bad += 1

        sys.stdout.write("\r OK: {}, Bad: {}, NoResponse: {}".format(self.ok, self.bad, self.noresp))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = HostPing()
    ips = api.create_ips("25.0.0.0", "25.255.255.255")
    pool = ThreadPool(30)
    pool.map(api.ping, ips)
    pool.wait_completion()
```

Comment: this is an I/O bound task here since you are waiting on sending and receiving packets from the host, it perhaps might be better to take an async approach given that is best suited for I/O bound tasks, regardless if you have 17M hosts to ping it will still take some time

Comment: yeah seems that could fasten up with async. Tnx for input.

Answer (score 1):

```
command = ['ping', '-c', '1', '-n', '1', '-w', '2',  address]
```

That's not a good match for your task.

You'd be happier using [fping](https://fping.org/fping.1.html).
It *is* fast, and is happy to accept multiple targets / ranges.

It's worth noting that ICMP is a host-to-host protocol,
there's no port number for the kernel to demux on
to allow for process-to-process packet dispatch.
So if you have dozens of `ping` child processes,
they **all** wake up on **every** response packet,
perform an equality test, and typically reject
the incoming packet as "not for me".
So `fping`, which recognizes diverse targets,
is far more efficient.

Comment: fping is not available for Win OS as far as I can tell. But you did give me some ideas to work with.